# Copying data from one pointer to another seg fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm a bit rusty with my C skills and the other day I was working on an assignment and came across some pointers. I don't know why, but this has completely stumped me. So, please forgive me if the solution is trivial.

I wrote up the following code to copy the data in one pointer to another. I don't want to use memcpy, strcpy or any other function.

```
char *word = "hello world!";
char *ptra = NULL;

ptra = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);

for (; word != '\0'; word++, ptra++) {
    *ptra = *word;
}

*ptra = '\0';
```

Now, when I compile this, I get a segmentation fault. Could anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: The bug is easy to fix but could be a bit tricky to spot, especially if you're new to pointers. Don't worry, it will get easier. Also, good job on the `+ 1` in your memory allocation. This is something that people (especially new programmers) forget and which causes all sorts of difficult to track down bugs.

Comment: In the program, you have incremented the pointer directly without making a copy. Hence, even after you perform the copy, you may not be able to use the string nor will you be able to free the memory at the end of the program. Making a copy of the pointers will help.

Comment: Excellent point @Ganesh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a dereferende: it should be `*word != '\0'` in the loop condition:

```
for (; *word != '\0'; word++, ptra++) {
    // ^ Here
    *ptra = *word;
}
```

Since `word` is a pointer, it would never be equal to `\0`, so your loop is going past the end of both strings.

Comment: Also, it would be nice if the OP would get in the habit of checking the result of `malloc` before using it.

Comment: Thanks very much das and Nik. Nik, I agree with you. Should I be using assert or just an if statement? So by this I mean, after I malloc, can I use 'assert (ptra != NULL)' or 'if (ptra == NULL) then print error message' ?

Comment: You should be using an `if` statement for this type of thing. Remember, an `assert` will usually only work in "debug" builds of your program and when it fails it will cause the program to exit immediately. Think of an `assert` as saying: "this thing should **never** happen, and if it does, panic, throw your hands up in the air, cry like a little girl and wait for me!" A memory allocation failure doesn't really (or, I should probably say *usually*) fit that criterion.